# Can an XNA game use more than 1.5GB of RAM and not crash?

Tags: memory, xna, out-of-memory

I wonder if it's possible to load tons of textures into memory for an XNA game and not get out of memory exceptions somehow.

Specifically load textures from filestreams during runtime.

Comment: WHY would you need to do that?

Comment: Tons of HiRes textures for one level\map\demo. Why wouldn't I?

Comment: I think the question you're asking may be one reason why you wouldn't. Basically, that is an absurd amount of texture data for a single environment. Even AAA developers need to work within limitations on proprietary high-end engines, which is why tiled and LOD textures are employed, in addition to repeating meshes and other assets.

Answer (score 5):

Doing this is a horrible idea for reasons that have nothing to do with the amount of addressable system memory (which, as you've noted, is limited to around ~2GB by the fact that XNA is a 32-bit library).

In order to be rendered, textures must be loaded into video memory on the graphics card.  These days, high-end desktop graphics cards have around 2-3GB; low- and mid-end cards have considerably less.  This memory is used not just for textures, but for all objects that exist on the video card, such as vertex buffers.  And if you're not running in exclusive mode, this memory is going to potentially be shared between multiple applications.  Exceeding the amount of available video memory is going to cause significant performance degradation due to swapping.

If you're really intent on filling up that video buffer (say, you're writing an ultra-high-end graphics mode for a AAA game), you'd have to either employ some advanced memory addressing techniques involving the Win32 API or load the textures into the graphics device without keeping a copy around in system memory.  These techniques are outside the scope of XNA.

Comment: As an addendum, if you're set on implementing such an absurd amount of texture data in a single environment, you could zone the area and unload old textures load news ones where approptiate. You'll undoubtedly take a performance hit at the cross-over, but that's better than continual performance issue with ongoing swapping in the graphics memory.